# javascript nullifies when setting the document.body.innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Good day.

I am currently working on a project that prints a desired `<div>` to a printer.

Here is the code:

```
    var printContents = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
    document.body.style.display = "none";

    window.print();

    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
    document.body.style.display = "block";
```

This code works and prints the desired `<div>`, but after that I need to put back the previous page again so I used this statement:

```
document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
document.body.style.display = "block";
```

This displays the previous page but the **functionalities of my buttons are gone**?! Can someone explain to me what happened and is there a solution to this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

This is happening because you've wiped out the old DOM which had events wired up to it, and replaced it with a totally new, different DOM that just happens to have the same HTML.

Presumably you're taking this approach because the printable zone is determined at runtime. A less-destructive solution might be to create a new `<iframe>` and copy the desired markup into that; then invoke `print()` on the iframe. Something like:

```
var printElement = function(element) {
    var frame = document.createElement('iframe');
    document.appendChild(frame);
    frame.contentDocument.innerHTML = element.innerHTML;
    frame.contentWindow.print();
    document.removeChild(frame);
};
```

You'll also need to copy over any CSS references into the `<iframe>`.

(note this is pseudo-code and *not* tested)

Comment: ohh, so that's what is happening. One question though, how can I load or perhaps retain the old dom? could you suggest work arounds with my situation? thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code clears the document and then puts back the HTML stored in originalContents, but this variable stores only a string, so all previously registered event handlers are gone.

Why don't you create a print stylesheet and hide everything except the content that you want to print?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
```

Answer (score 0):

When you reset the innerHTML, you don't get all your event handlers back.  They are wiped out when you create entirely new DOM elements.

One idea would be to have two master divs in the body, one that is your normal display and one that is what you want to print.  You can then hide whichever one you don't want to display like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="mainContent">main screen content goes here</div>
    <div id="printContent">generated print content goes here</div>
</body>

// hide main content
var mainDiv = document.getElementById("mainContent");
mainDiv.style.display = "none";
// put content to print in the print div and show it
var printDiv = document.getElementById("printContent");
printDiv.innerHTML = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
printDiv.style.display = "block";

// print
window.print();

// restore visibility
mainDiv.style.display = "block";
printDiv.style.display = "none;
```

You could also just use the whole body for printing and use a stylesheet with `media="print"` to control the visibility of the things you do/don't want to print.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a click event to all dives inside your page so that user can click the div.
after that add a class to that div which the class is defined within the print CSS file.
inside css print file use the following code:

```
`*{display:none}
.printableDiv{display:block}`
```

to define a print css file use this code :
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">` (which Rafael has told you ).
good luck